# How to modify Enum attributes (extracting dataclass)?

Tags: python, inheritance, enums, multiple-inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have my dataclasses:

```py
@dataclass
class BaseObject(ABC):
    obj: int
    data: Union[str, int, float, None] = None
    datatype: ClassVar[type]
    datalen: ClassVar[int]
    readonly: bool = True

@dataclass
class StrObject(BaseObject):
    datatype = str
    datalen = 16
```

and similar subclasses for Int and Float.

Now my goal is to achive something like belove enum class:

e.g.

```py
class ObjectsPSI9000(Enum):
    DEVICE_TYPE = StrObject(next_id())
    DEVICE_SN = StrObject(next_id())
    NOMINAL_VOLT = FloatObject(next_id())
    NOMINAL_CURR = FloatObject(next_id())
```

But getting attributes value is annoying (e.g. `DEVICE_TYPE.value.obj`).

Is it any way to "unpack" my dataclass content to make it more comfortable to use?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where accessing the `value` is a common need, the usual method is to make the enum inherit from the same data type, such as `IntEnum` when the values are `int`s.  However, in this case each enum member is a different data type (`StrObject`, 'FloatObject`, etc.).  The easiest thing to do is add` property`s to handle getting the` .value` attributes:

```
class ObjectsPSI9000(Enum):
    #
    DEVICE_TYPE = StrObject(1)
    DEVICE_SN = StrObject(2)
    NOMINAL_VOLT = FloatObject(3)
    NOMINAL_CURR = FloatObject(4)
    #
    @property
    def obj(self):
        return self.value.obj
    #
    @property
    def datatype(self):
        return self.value.datatype
    #
    # etc.
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Property.. In my code it's everywhere. :D Thanks for answer.
I resolved it by adding `name: str = field(init=False)` in BaseObject and  
```for name in ObjectsPSI9000.object_names(): getattr(ObjectsPSI9000, name).name = name```
Just after `ObjectsPSI9000` definition and the result is what i need but it doesnt look elegant. (`object_names` returns names of  attributes class up to first one starting with `_`).